# Javascript: When putting an if in a function, is there anything that needs to be added?

Tags: javascript

I'm "newer" to JavaScript, and was wondering if anything needs to be added when putting an `if` in a Function. This is my code. I want to be able to use one function to call another function that alerts the page.

```
function Function() {
  var var1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML = var1;
  Functions();
}

function Functions() {
  if (var1 == 1) {
    Question1();
  }
}

function Question1() {
  alert("works");
}
```

Comment: You'll need to learn a bit about variable scope. The `var1` in `Function` is not reachable from `Functions`. It would be if JS had dynamic scoping, but it doesn't.

Comment: No, but `Functions` doesn't have access to `var1`.  You would have to pass it in as an argument from `Function`.

Comment: it's also customary to not capitalize funcs unless they are constructors

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with `if`, but with variable scope.

Variables declared with `var` are local to the function, they can't be accessed from another function. You should pass the value as an argument to the other function.

```
function Function() {
  var var1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML = var1;
  Functions(var1);
}

function Functions(var2) {
  if (var2 == 1) {
    Question1();
  }
}

function Question1() {
  alert("works");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick lesson about variable scopes: Variables only exist in the scope they are defined in

Because of that, in your definition of `Functions` the variable `var2` would be undefined.

Two solutions

1. Pass the variable through parameters, i.e when calling `Functions`, pass var2 through the parameters like `Functions(var2)`, and the catch the value within the function body
2. Define `var2` globally, so both functions can see the value. Although, this is often considered bad practice